abp-framework and openiddict multitenant application error - The authentication demand was rejected because the token had no valid audience
I have an abp-framework and openiddict multi-tenant application with asp.net core UI. A tenant can register and I can see the tenant and related administrator user in the database. However, when the tenant tries to log in they get the following error message. There is the no audience message and also The specified access token is bound to an account that no longer exists. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction
2024-12-08 11:04:32.249 +13:00 [INF] The userinfo request was successfully validated.
2024-12-08 11:04:32.273 +13:00 [INF] **The authentication demand was rejected because the token had no valid audience.**
2024-12-08 11:04:32.274 +13:00 [INF] OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
2024-12-08 11:04:32.285 +13:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Controllers.UserInfoController.Userinfo (Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore)'
2024-12-08 11:04:32.291 +13:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "Userinfo", controller = "UserInfo", area = "", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Userinfo() on controller Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Controllers.UserInfoController (Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore).
2024-12-08 11:04:32.291 +13:00 [INF] Skipping the execution of current filter as its not the most effective filter implementing the policy Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IAntiforgeryPolicy
2024-12-08 11:04:32.293 +13:00 [INF] Executing action method Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Controllers.UserInfoController.Userinfo (Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore) - Validation state: "Valid"
2024-12-08 11:04:32.537 +13:00 [INF] Executed action method Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Controllers.UserInfoController.Userinfo (Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 244.2183ms.
2024-12-08 11:04:32.539 +13:00 [INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore"]).
2024-12-08 11:04:32.555 +13:00 [INF] The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "**The specified access token is bound to an account that no longer exists**.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2025"

